# Getting full URL using form action Submit from torrent page

Tags: rss

I am trying to setup my seedbox to automatically download torrents.
I am using the site's RSS feed but the feed provies a list of pages of the torrents. These pages contain a button ("Download") of type "submit".

So when I load the feed on rTorrent in my seedbox, I can see the contents but I cannot download anything because they are not direct links to the downloads.

I was wondering if there is a way grab/find these direct download links, or somehow trasnsform the torrent URL to include the form action submit.